# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC and Entity Framework Core 7.0 - can't connect to Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I just upgraded from EF 6 -> EF Core 7 in my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app because I needed the `context.Database.SqlQuery<T>()` functionality; however, when I try to run any query via EF it now appears unable to connect at all when I build & run or execute migration cmds:

```
C:\Path\To\My\Project\Ui>dotnet ef database update --context sqliteascertodbcontext
Build started...
Build succeeded.
  Debug: Registered integration with EF Core.
```

> An error occurred using the connection to database 'main' on server 'C:\Path\To\My\Project\Ui\db.sqlite3'.
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: ''.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.LoadExtensionCore(String file, String proc)
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()
> at     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteScalar(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> SQLite Error 1: ''.

CSProject contents:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="6.0.11" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core" Version="7.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="7.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" Version="7.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.5" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="7.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.0">
       <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
       <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
   </PackageReference>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin" Version="4.2.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.17.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security" Version="4.2.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" Version="4.2.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt" Version="4.2.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.23.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Sentry.AspNetCore" Version="3.22.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.6.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3" Version="2.1.3" />
   <PackageReference Include="VueCliMiddleware" Version="3.1.2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Is there anything missing, or?

Comment: Show how you have configured `DbContextOptions`.

Comment: Also try to remove package reference `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3`

Comment: @marc_s, please do not put stack trace in quotes - it is less readable. Stack trace has sense line by line.